# Nodejs parse child_process (or execa) stdout

Tags: node.js, parsing, child-process

I'm trying to separate the heaviest tasks in child process. I'm doing it with Execa but it's the same as child_process.

How can I parse the stdout value?

**Caller:**

```
public static async testExecaArray() {
    const arr = ["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6"]
    const { stdout } = await execa("node", ["/testExecaArray.js", JSON.stringify(arr)])

    //This is what I want to parse: stdout
    console.log(stdout)
}
```

**testExecaArray.js:**

```
let argv = process.argv.slice(2)

if (argv.length >= 1) {
    let arr = JSON.parse(argv[0])

    //I'm returning two arrays:
    console.log(arr)
    console.log(arr.slice(2))
}
```

Thanks in advance!!!